# Text appearing over image when it should only appear on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am attempting to create an effect using jQuery, where when the user hovers over an image, a piece of text appears over the image. However, there are a few issues when making changes to the code.

1. If the ".img" on line 3 of the jQuery is replaced with "img", the code works fine, but causes the hover effect to work on a different image
2. If I remove the semicolon after "opacity: 0.75;" on line 4 of the jQuery, the code works temporarily, but any other interactions with the page causes the effect to break

Apologies for the code being a bit long winded.

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9dsL2jyL/3/

My Code:

HTML

```
<div class="workInfo">
        <!-- Nav bar open icon -->
        <img src="images/icons/navbar.png" id="hamburger" alt="Navigation Menu" onclick="openNav()">
        <!-- Nav bar links -->
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()" alt="Close the Navigation Menu">&times;</a>
            <a href="index.html" class="toplink" alt="Home">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html" alt="About">About</a>
            <a href="portfolio.html" alt="Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="#" alt="Contact ">Contact</a>
            <!-- Facebook Link -->
            <a href="#" id="facebook" alt="Facebook Page Link">
                <div class="container">
                    <img src="images/icons/facebookHover.png">
                    <img class="fadeTop" src="images/icons/facebook.png" style="display: block;">
                </div>
            </a>                    
            <!-- Instagram Link -->     
            <a href="#" id="instagram" alt="Instagram Page Link">   
                <div class="container">
                    <img src="images/icons/instagramhover.png">
                    <img class="fadeTop" src="images/icons/instagram.png">
                </div>
            </a>                    
            <!-- Github Link --> 
            <a href="#" id="github" alt="Github Page Link">
                <div class="container">
                    <img src="images/icons/githubhover.png">
                    <img class="fadeTop" src="images/icons/github.png">
                </div>
            </a> 
        </div>
        <h1>Work</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="workDisplay">
        <a href="#">
            <!-- Div to store the text for hover -->                    
            <div id="container">  
                <!-- Text that appears on hover -->
                <h2 class="text">
                    A Play On Words
                </h2>
            </div>  
            <!-- Project image -->
            <img class="img" src="images/cardphoto.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.sidenav {
/* Sets the height to 100% of the page */
height: 100%;
/* Sets the width of the nav bar to 0 */
width: 0;
/* Keeps the nav bar stationary */
position: fixed;
/* Makes the nav bar appear above everything */
z-index: 10;
/* Nav bar Placement stuff */
top: 0;
left: 0;
/* Sets the colour of the nav bar background */
background-color: #141311;
/* Disables horizontal scroll in the nav bar */
overflow-x: hidden;
/* Adds padding above the content */
padding-top: 3%;
/* Adds 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the nav bar */
transition: 0.5s;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
/* Sets the font */
font-family: "purista-web",sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 300;
/* Adds padding around the links */
padding: 1vh 1vw 1vh 2vw; 
/* Removes all text decoration */
text-decoration: none;
/* Sets the size of the font */
font-size: 1.75vw;
/* Sets the colour of the font */
color: #B8B8B4;
/* Makes the text appear in a block */
display: block;
/* Adds a 0.3s transition to the hover effect */
transition: 0.3s
}

/* Styling for the social media links */
.container {
position: relative;
width: 5vw;
padding-top: 5vh;
padding-bottom: 5vh;
}

.container img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 5vw;
}

/* Changes the colour when you hover over the link */
.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
color: #FEFEFA;
}

/* Styling for the top link of the nav bar */
.toplink {
margin-top: 10vh;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.closebtn {
position: absolute;
top: -4.5vh;
font-size: 8vw !important;
}

/* Styling for the left half of the portfolio page */
.workInfo {
/* Keeps the div fixed in one position */
position: fixed;
/* Removes White surrounding boxes */
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
/* Sets the Width and height of the div, and the background colour */
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
background: #FEFEFA;
z-index: 5;
}

/* Styling for Work */
.workInfo h1 {
/* Sets the font */
font-family: "marydale",sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
/* Sets the size of the font */
font-size: 8vw;
/* Sets the positioning for the text */
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -13vh;
margin-left: -34vw;
/* Sets the colour of the type */
color: #141311;
}

.workInfo #hamburger {
width: 3vw;
position: absolute; 
left: 5%; 
top: 5.5%; 
}

/* Styling for the right half of the portfolio page */
.workDisplay {
/* Keeps the div fixed in one position */
position: fixed;
/* Removes White surrounding boxes */
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
/* Sets the Width and height of the div, and the background colour */
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
background: #141311;
line-height: 100%;
z-index: 4;
display: -moz-flex; 
display: -webkit-flex; 
display: flex;             
flex-direction: column;     
justify-content: center;   
align-items: center;       
}

.workDisplay #container {
/* Keeps the div fixed in one position */
position: fixed;
/* Removes White surrounding boxes */
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
/* Sets the Width and height of the div, and the background colour */
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
}

.workDisplay h2 {
color: #FEFEFA;
/* Sets the typeface */
font-family: "skolar-sans-latin",sans-serif;
/* Makes the font italic */
font-style: italic;
/* Makes the font Bold */
font-weight: 700;
/* Sets the size of the type */
font-size: 3vw;
margin-top: 48vh;
display: -moz-flex; 
display: -webkit-flex; 
display: flex;             
flex-direction: column;     
justify-content: center;   
align-items: center; 
z-index: 14;
}

.workDisplay img {
display: block;
height: 100vh;
min-height: 100vh;
width: auto;
z-index: 10;
}
```

jQuery

```
/* Hover effect for the nav bar */
$(window).load(function(){
$(".container").hover(function() {
    //Adds a fade out of 300ms to the top image
    $(this).find(".fadeTop").fadeOut(300);
}, function() {
    //Adds a fade in of 300ms to the top image
    $(this).find(".fadeTop").fadeIn(300);
});
})


/* Hover effect for the span's on the work page */
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.text').hide();
    $('.img').animate({
        opacity: 0.75
    });

    $('.img').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:.4},200);
        $('.text').fadeIn();

    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1},500)
        $('.text').fadeOut();
    });
```

Comment: Please add a jsFiddle so we can see the behavior you currently have

Comment: FYI, there's a wrongly placed `\`` in your CSS definition: `top: \`0;` -- not sure if it's related, I noticed by going through the edit review queue

Comment: No relation but cheers, probably wouldn't have picked up on that otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who reads this later, I found that the  tag surrounding the image in the workDisplay div was causing the issue, as upon removing this tag from my code, the hover effect worked perfectly.

HTML Before:

```
<div class="workDisplay">
    <a href="#">
        <!-- Div to store the text for hover -->                    
        <div id="container">  
            <!-- Text that appears on hover -->
            <h2 class="text">
                A Play On Words
            </h2>
        </div>  
        <!-- Project image -->
        <img class="img" src="images/cardphoto.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

HTML After:

```
<div class="workDisplay">
        <!-- Div to store the text for hover -->                    
        <div id="container">  
            <!-- Text that appears on hover -->
            <h2 class="text">
                A Play On Words
            </h2>
        </div>  
        <!-- Project image -->
        <img class="img" src="images/cardphoto.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **JQuery**, images can be selected by image element `$("img")` or by class or id of a image `$(".imageclass")` and `$("#imageid")` respectively.

In your case, you can provide additional class to the images you want to select by JQuery `animate` function. Then the function will only affect the images who have that class only. Hope this makes it clear.

`$(".imageclass").animate({
        opacity: 0.75;
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use JS 
when it can be solved by Css

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}
.box-item{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
}
.box-item:hover .box-item-text{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, -50%) scale(1);
}
.box-item:hover .box-item-img{
  opacity: .8;
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
 filter: blur(3px);
  // http://caniuse.com/#search=filter%3A%20blur
}
.box-item-text{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%) scale(.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 500ms linear;
}
.box-item-img{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  // or background-size: cover !important;
  background-size: 100% 100% !important;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
 filter: blur(0px);
  transition: all 500ms linear; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-item">
    <div class="box-item-text">Lorem ipsum.</div>
    <div class="box-item-img" style="background: url(http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff) 0 0 no-repeat;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-item">
    <div class="box-item-text">Lorem ipsum.</div>
    <div class="box-item-img" style="background: url(http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff) 0 0 no-repeat;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```